# Are there any tools that support Database query submission, review, approval and execution workflow?

Tags: mysql

We are a very small setup in the e-commerce space. More than often there is a need to correct data manually in our MySQL database via SQL query execution. There is 1 database administrator in our setup. He is currently getting overwhelmed with the manual query execution and needs to be available every day for some part of the day for query execution.

I am searching for a database query administration tool that can :

1. Allows an end-user (submitter) to raise a database query execution request
2. Allows a DBA (reviewer) to review database query and approve/reject a query
3. Executes approved query on the selected database and emails results back to submitter and reviewer both.

A very simple tool can be built inhouse however the engineering teams bandwidth is not available.

Comment: Have you looked at remote admin tool?

Comment: No. Could you be more specific? I need a tool which my development team can access on web and then submit DDL/DML requests for approval.

Comment: I presume that these MySQL machines are on customer site? Can't you install phpMyAdmin (or similar tool) and remotely access these client machines? Then submit the DDL/DML requests via email? I know of no tool that does precisely what you appear to want - unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: The MySQL machines are for the e-commerce backend. I am a senior member of this team of backend team. I am looking to build a maker-checker workflow for SQL query execution requests raised by developers. Right now everything is managed via emails and copy-pasting commands to MySQL prompt.

Comment: Well, maybe you'll have more luck during the week - it's a Sunday morning where I am and there probably aren't that many lurkers right now! Maybe you should develop your own tool and then market it - sounds like a good idea to me and "eating your own . dogfood" is a good way to make a good product!. I'm giving the question a +1 - p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Fix the design that allows bad data to enter the system (e.g. [Check Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html), [Foreign Key Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), [validated user data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation), etc.).  Your current approach is inherently risky and will eventually result in an improper update, especially since you have identified your DBA is already becoming overwhelmed with these sort of requests.